# Measuring distance between certain relations in QGIS

Tags: qgis, measurements, distance-matrix, connection, spatial-relationship

[image: The busstop pairs can be seen here]I need to measure the direct distance between busstops in meters, not taking roads/networks into account.

I have the WGS 84 Coordinates + globalIDs for 28.000 pairs.

I already imported the Busstops from a csv (UTF-8) into a point layer.

My previous atempts:

- Distance Matrix doesn´t work, because of the huge data size 28.000 x 28.000 is too much "waste" data and the operation fails...
- "Point Connector" tool just creates "lines" without any measurments

The output should be 28.000 Lines with the distance in meters in a CSV, or just simply the measurment in m for every busstop relation.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just in order to clarify: You want to know, how far it is from busstop A to B, then from B to C, etc. And this for every line? I guess the busstops have attributes concerning the lines?

Comment: More like. Busstop A to B, C to D, E to F.

Comment: But why is B to C or D to E not of interest?

Comment: Add some sample data and/or screenshots

Comment: The relations are the output of a transportation company and show the tickets purchased from all the ticket-sales. I need to measure the distance from a excact set pair of busstops.

Comment: Posted the Csv file I need to work with.

Comment: Are you interested in the distance along the road, or does "as the crow flies" suffice?

Comment: just the path of a bird :D "direct path"

Comment: Btw, you coordinates are missing a decimal separator - currently they look like UTM coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand you but if you have the table you show you could try using pyqgis to calculate distance:

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer() #Click layer/table in tree. I have a excel table

#https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/266360/pyqgis-when-we-search-based-on-the-distance-between-two-points-is-the-measurem
distance = QgsDistanceArea()
distance.setEllipsoid('WGS84')

fieldnames = [f.name() for f in layer.fields() if f.name().startswith(('fr','to'))] #List fields starting with fr and to
field_to_update = 'distance' #Change to match the field you want to store distances in

with edit(layer):
    for f in layer.getFeatures():
        p1 = QgsPointXY(f[fieldnames[0]]/100000,f[fieldnames[1]]/100000)
        p2 = QgsPointXY(f[fieldnames[2]]/100000,f[fieldnames[3]]/100000)
        m = distance.measureLine(p1, p2)
        f.setAttribute(f.fieldNameIndex(field_to_update),m)
        layer.updateFeature(f)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your support.

I managed to do it.

Use the plugin "PointConnector" to create lines between the busstops.
Then just use the "add Geometricattribute" tool.

Easy but very effetive.

Tipp 1: Only use WGS 84
Tipp 2: Be careful while creating the from-to-list for PointConnector. Excel rounds the zeros , therefor 10 is converted to 1.
Tipp 3: PointConnector: Read the Python concole if errors accur. It helps alot to understand what went wrong. Sometimes just a new project with the same steps solves the problem. Or you can use the "repair geometrie" tool

Hope this helps.